# Changing default CSS from meteor template

Tags: css, meteor

This is a pretty basic question but I can't figure out why I can't change the css from the tabs template in Meteor. https://github.com/meteortemplates/tabs

I've installed the template and I am trying to change the css from the "active" tab. When I do inspect element, I'm seeing that the css file it's using is a "template_tabs.css" instead of the one I have in my root directory. I have no idea where this file is. I did a search in all my directories and can't find it.

Shouldn't my main css file in the root directory override this? If not, how do I edit this template_tabs.css file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It likely had to do with file load order: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp You want your custom CSS files to load after the package CSS files have loaded.

Alternatively, you could mark your CSS with `!important` e.g.

```
div.sample { 
    background: none; 
    width: 200px !important }
```

In this example width will be set to 200px no matter when the file loads. I am not quite sure how it deals with conflicts if the style was marked `!important` in multiple files with different values.

I think it would be best not to mess with the original package CSS as that will be overwritten when it updates.